# Undefined Variable PHP Class

Tags: php

I'm trying to debug a class that I made.
It always breaks and throw undefined variable on the logs I couldn't find a solution because I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think it should work but not.

The undefined variable is on the `erase()` function, not in the `show()` function

```
class pepe{
 private $array = array();

 function show(){
   $this->erase();
   print_r($this->array);
 }
 function erase(){
   print_r($this->array); 
 }
}

$o = new pepe();
$s = $o->show();
```

Comment: it works to me:  `$s = $o->erase();`

Comment: It should work, i posted a simple example, in my code isnt working
http://pastebin.com/PsTXeJ6D

On line 110 it says undefined variable

Comment: Found the error made by me, it's not good to work at 3am. In my code i have $o->$array();

Thanks a lot people!

Answer (score 2):

```
class pepe{

private $array = array();

 

function show(){

$this->erase();

print_r($this->array);

}

function erase(){

print_r($this->array); 

}

}

 

$o = new pepe();

$s = pepe->show();
```

Why are you calling pepe here? Should be like this:

```
  class pepe{
    private $array = array();

 function show(){
   $this->erase();
   print_r($this->array);
 }
 function erase(){
   print_r($this->array); 
 }
}

$o = new pepe();
$s = $o->show();
```

You have to call

```
$o->show()
```

because you've assigned pepe to

```
$o
```